# Freestyle rendering in eevee is too slow

Tags: eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I am rendering using eevee and rendering is fine but rendering the freestyle takes a very long time. Shot 1 is perfectly fine but shot 7 is where I'm having trouble. Here are the two files:

shot 1: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52532

shot 7: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52533

Some help would be apreciated.

Comment: Please add images of your renders to the question.

Comment: https://www.online-convert.com/result/e7c23345-6ba7-4346-80fa-befa7e7c48ca

Comment: the problem isn't with the renders, but rendering is taking an awful amount of time